# Safest way to let an user set data to database

Tags: php, html, mysql, sql

Little background.
I'm making a forum with an account system.

So naturally they have to insert data to the database whilist speaking in the forums.

**What is the safest way to let the user input data in an textarea?**

Is there away so they can't just type in `DROP TABLE 'USERS'`, or something else that might effect my forum?

Now I know there is some solutions to this, but how can I do this so that they're able to make their text look nice `(<h1>,<img>)` etc, but not do a proper SQL query?

*Kinda like this page is made, I can type here with all sorts of looks but I cannot do anything to harm the page.*

Thanks.

-Kevin

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/9378/SQL-Injection-Attacks-and-Some-Tips-on-How-to-Prev

Comment: You should read about "SQL injections" and prevention of those. Most database APIs allow prepared statements and automatically escape dynamic content properly (when used correctly).

Answer (score 1):

Either [mysqli_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php) or [Prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) for **SQL injection**

To keep the **HTML injection**, just dont do anything. Queries are already vulnerable to HTML injection.

In your case you might just want to use an editor for your forum posts, like: [TinyMCE](http://www.tinymce.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You need to do (at least) two things:

1. Your database user should have only required grants on given table - so `GRANT INSERT on yourtable TO youruser` instead of `GRANT ALL on yourtable TO youruser`
2. Make yourself `sql injection` safe - by using [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in your php code